# ¿Cómo consigo cambiar la estética del grafico cuando separo por grupos?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy intentado hacer una réplica del gráfico que aparece en la imagen usando ggplot

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de separar los grupos por el área. He utilizado el siguiente código en R:

```
ggplot(lions, aes(age, prop.black, shape = sex, fill = area)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2)) + scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

Es decir, con shape me separa los grupos por sexo y con fill por el área. La separación por sexo sale bien (triángulos para machos y círculos para hembras). Sin embargo, el argumento fill no me hace nada y no entiendo por qué. Debería aparecer los de area = Serengueti con relleno y los del área Ngorongoro sin relleno.

Comment: ¿Probaste con  `group`?

Comment: sii, y no me los agrupa, te pongo el código por si lo estoy haciendo mal.  ```
ggplot(lions, aes(age, prop.black, shape = sex, group= area)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2)) 
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad necesitas crear una categoría nueva que integre el sexo con el área, incluso puedes crear el texto completo que incluye las cantidades mediante `mutate(area_sex = paste0(area, " ",sex, " (n=", n(), ")"))`, y únicamente necesitas la estética `shape`:

```
lions %>%
  group_by(area, sex) %>% 
  mutate(area_sex = paste0(area, " ",sex, " (n=", n(), ")")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(age, prop.black, shape = area_sex)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2, 15, 16)) + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1") +
  labs(
    x = "Age (yr)",
    y = "Proportion black",
    shape = ""
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, se ha graficado bien. Ahora el problema que me surge es que no puedo modificar la leyenda del gráfico. Intento utilizar  ```theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.1))```  para intentar que aparezca la leyenda dentro del gráfico pero no tiene efecto ninguno. Supongo que el problema esta en mutate, ya que la leyenda surge de ahí, pero no consigo solucionarlo

Comment: Lo he probado, y más o menos lo logré ubicar adecuadamente con `theme(legend.position = c(0.7, 0.25))`, pruebalo y sino puedes hacer otra pregunta. Saludos.